# Controlling Bluetooth smart switch in android.

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy

I am new to Bluetooth functions. I have a Bluetooth smart switch, I need to trigger it on/off using an application. Should I use a basic Bluetooth codes or the one with GATT? What kind of input should be given to the client device(Smart switch) to trigger them? How to find what kind of input should be given? Any guidance or code snippets or links will be very helpful. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You must first understand what is peripheral role and central role. Go through some sample codes and figure it out what you need to do.

[Bluetooth low energy Android tutorial](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html)